# Star sql ODBC driver- Displays database names as garbled text

Tags: database, odbc, db2, database-connection

I am using windows xp machine with defined ODBC connection for a DB2 database using star sql odbc driver.

When ever I tried to access the databases using the connection the crystal reports menu displays the garbled text. as shown.
[image]

Earlier the database names was displayed instead of this garbled text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by myself.

It seems the star sql Database driver associated with this ODBC connection needs to be updated. Issue is solved after updating the driver.